# How do I copy an RPM from a remote repo to a local one?

Tags: rpm

We've got a local RPM repo server, and not infrequently we need to find software that's hosted in external repos and migrate it so that it's hosted locally instead.

How do you copy an external RPM hosted in an external repo to a local repo?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a local repo?  As for how you copy an rpm, however you want; it's just a file.  Use cp, use wget, use scp, use rsync.. Whether that RPM is a part of an existing repo or not makes no difference to the RPM itself.

Comment: How do I know what the path is to the RPM? Directory structure? Do I need to copy a number of files, or just the RPM file itself?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this command and get download the directory which you contains the RPM files.

wget -r --no-parent http:// directory/path/to/remote/server

Answer (score 1):

Getting the file has already been covered.

If you want to add an rpm to an existing yum repo, you would put the file with the other rpms and run:

createrepo --update /path/to/repository/root

This will update the metadata needed to make the package available.